# Parameters of a GET request are put into the query string of the URL. In a POST request, they are in the request body, so what does the URL look like?

Tags: java, http, url, post, servlets

For example I may have a HTML form that uses a get method and produces the URL:

http://localhost:8080/HelloForm?Name=Gareth+Wylie&Age=24&Formula=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21

for the the key-value pairs:

```
Name: Gareth Wylie 

Age: 24 

Formula: a + b == 13%!
```

and for `HelloForm.java` (e.g. using java servlets)

If I had the same HTML form, but used the POST request, what would the URL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL will be same as `GET` with the query parameters omitted. That is:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloForm
```

Comment: Dude everything clicked when I read this. Turns out I was really confused by everything and my question is not really accurate and doesn't mean what I think it does...

Thank you!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I had struggle time when begin with web development too. So don't hesitate to ask.